# How to keep rendering of a child in line with rendering of parent, without using ref()?

Tags: vuejs3

My grandchild component relies on data that is calculated in its parent's `onUpdated` hook. The problem is that the grandchild is always one step behind the child. Some simplified code below which shows the problem, which is also on the [vue playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqlU8Fu2zAM/RVBlyZokLTJLXOMbUU3bMC2Yutuurg246iVJUGSuwCG/30UHdvNMrQFekhg8j2SjyLZ8A/Wzh9r4Gue+NxJG5iHUFvGVKbLjeDBC54KLStrXGANc7BlLds6U7EzjDsboKudVMUBmC/IiomRIHRutA+s8iXbxASTy6nQyaKrh8nRCFBZlQVAK7mrQzCavc+VzB9Qwvk5RqIKqXMHmYdk0TEid3eZfoM1axrK3rbJAj1CM5Z0etZFFjKsimiadKpi2GKox2fYIurbynJ+743Gh2hivOC5qaxU4H7YIFG/4FgmIhHLlDJ/vpIvuBpmvT/fQf7wH/+930ef4DcOPLhHEHzAQuZKCB18/es77PF7ACtT1ArZz4A/wRtVR40d7WOtC5T9hEdqv9CYpC5v/fU+gPZ9U1FoZLbEFxyHdvVM66Pc1XxFcUK3+IrDxE9W6WiT3JNdMvq3xflAcbxRI+Wzy3RxvFhldOXjdiE5/roNs85Yj9MuYCs13EQraSLMGO3Bmum6usO3QVebTqZ9tIJAhOW7aG1rnce+WdwABftPB3sSKVN8CUqIvd3KCkwdJpPpJqVwLE0S5tGaLS8uppSwjX9Ds0hnm7RPw06qjBkO0YPM8WR6x3g2lCzZLVN6LroIaplOYtnj44Meqvf3QfJ7RXgpI5FCjw/meAYvzvvt83lF46uUJJOqf7pfnbTQ/gUzMLQN)

App.vue:

```
<script setup  lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Child from './Child.vue'

const msg = ref(1)
</script>

<template>
<button @click="++msg">increase</button>
<h1>Me: {{ msg }}</h1>
  <Child :data = msg></Child>
</template>
```

Child:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onUpdated } from 'vue'
import GrandChild from './grandchild.vue'

const props = defineProps<{   data : number  }>()
let data2;

function complexFunction(data) {
  setTimeout(()=>data2 = props.data,200);
}

onUpdated(() => {
    complexFunction(props.data);
})

</script>

<template>
  <h2>Child: {{ data }}</h2>
  <GrandChild   :data = data2 ></GrandChild>
</template>
```

Grandchild:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

const props = defineProps<{   data : number  }>()

</script>

<template>
  <h3>Grandchild: {{ data }}</h3>
</template>
```

In the real case, `complexFunction` uses some libraries (leafletjs and plugins) to calculate `data2` (which is a complex object, not a simple number!). In the simplified version I have used a timeout to represent this.

If I use a ref() for `data2`, the grandchild updates as expected (in the simplified example here) but using ref() in the real case the `complexFunction` causes `onUpdated` to call itself, resulting in stack overflow. I have tried and failed to find out why, so I am looking for a solution that will update without using ref().

There's a partial solution [here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) which updates the grandchild correctly after *every second click*. I need to keep the data shown in child and grandchild equal at all times, i.e.

> Me: 9 Child: 9 Grandchild: 9

and not

> Me: 9 Child: 9 Grandchild: 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onUpdated` is called every time the DOM tree updates.  If the hook updates a value that updates the DOM, that would cause an infinite loop.

A [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) would work better. It runs a callback only when some specific state is updated. In your case, whenever `data` updates, you want to update `data2` (as a ref) via your `complexFunction` function

```js
watch(() => props.data, () => {
    complexFunction(props.data);
  }, { immediate: true }
)
```

[updated Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thankyou. I had tried `watch` but not to actually replace `onUpdated`. Actually I still had the infinite loop with `watch` as well, until I changed `onUpdated` in the grandchild to `onBeforeUpdate`. Since the update task in the grandchild also takes time (both child and grandchild are drawing graphics), I assume that one task finishing was interrupting the other somehow, and causing an unnecessary update.